# Send whatsapp contact card when click a button

Tags: web, message, contacts, whatsapp, vcf-vcard

I've already a service that allows me to send message to a whatsapp number, now what I need is to make a button on my web and when somebody click it, send my contact card to them, so they can add me to their phone directory.

I found this code that open your whatsapp with a new conversation with the number you define:

> href = "intent://send/0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end";

but it only success if you have my number in your whatsapp conversations or in your contacts book already.

Any idea??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I made a .vcf file and a link to it to download it into the reader's contact book. As simple as:

```
<a href="mycontact.vcf">download contact</a>
```